# DNS/nameserver overlay/reverse proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-proxy, nameserver

We use a 3rd party application to organize our projects. This application provides their own nameserver, the domain itself (say *fooapp.com*) is ours.
Now we'd like to add additional subdomains to *fooapp.com*. As the application does not provide any way to add additional records, we are looking for some kind of nameserver reverse-proxy.

This proxy would serve records for our additional subdomain (e.g. *test.fooapp.com*) and forward all other queries to *ns1.3rdparty.com*.

Is there any way we can implement such a system? If so, are there any hosted services available (I'm not that comfortable hosting my own nameservers)?

Comment: And which application might this be?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being specific enough. It's a custom-built project management software which creates subdomains for each project. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.